# Написать функцию, которая принимает массив строк, а выводит строку, которая поочередно забрала элементы с конца и начала

Tags: javascript, массивы

Написать функцию, чтобы выводилось вот так: console.log(move(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])); // "afbecd"
Вывод в строку я реализовал, а вот функцию, которая забирает элементы с конца и начала никак не могу написать.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

var str = arr.reduce(function move(str, el, index, arr){
  return str + el;
});

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если очень просто, то можновот так -

```js
const f = array => {
  let clone = [...array];
  let length = clone.length;
  let result = '';
  
  for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    result += i % 2 === 0 ? clone.shift() : clone.pop();
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]));
console.log(f(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]));
```

Так даже лучше -

```js
const f = array => array.reduce((result, item, index, array) => {
  let i = Math.floor(index / 2);
  let length = array.length - 1;
  let isEven = index % 2 === 0;
  let word = array[isEven ? i : length - i];
  
  return result + word;
}, '');


console.log(f(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']));
console.log(f(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']));
```

Comment: но если я добавлю еще один элемент к массиву, то будет неправильно

Comment: @Igor внес изменения.